# What kind of data structure would I use to house an infinite grid?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

I need to figure out how to make an infinite board (kind of like what wordsquared.com uses) that can expand on demand without losing the location of objects that are already on the board.

What data structure(s) would I use to create a similar board?

I should also mention that I will need to do location queries, and be able to check the surroundings of a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list.  When you add an object to the board, add it to the list.  When you remove an object from the board, remove it from the list.  This is `O(1)` for insertion and deletion, which is as fast as it gets.  Each object has an `(x,y)` coordinate.

Or did you have something else in mind?  I can only answer the questions that you actually ask...

Comment: So the board itself would only exist as a concept, and I would keep track of all objects on the list? How would I go about checking surroundings? Also wouldn't the list become very very large at some point?

Comment: The list only becomes large if you put a lot of objects in it.  But everything becomes large if you put a lot of objects in it.  It is not designed for location queries -- you should put that in the question.

Comment: Instead of a list, you could use an associative data structure, like a map, with your coordinates as a key.  As with this list solution, your data structure scales with the number of items rather than the extent of the grid (which is conceptual).  The coordinate keys let you do location-based queries.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of off hand:

1. Allocate a pool of nodes each of which has a pointer to the node above, below, to the left and to the right of the current node.  Since your board should only grow, you won't have to deal with any ugly deletions.  Keep a pointer to the top-left of the board for easy rendering (the traversal is simple and obvious).
2. Allocate a matrix of nodes and use it as-is.  When you need to grow your board, allocate a new one and copy the data from the old to the new before deleting it.  This will be a bit slow on reallocation, but will make for easy interaction with the board.

Comment: I like your first idea, do you think that a script for traversing surrounding nodes of x depth will run slowly?

Comment: No, it should run fairly well.  Assuming you have the top-left pointer, set your row pointer to it.  The columns of each row are found by following the right-of pointers until null, and successive rows begin with the below pointer of the current row, until null.  You have some small overhead traversing the lists, but for an "infinite" board, you're going to have to make a trade-off somewhere.

Comment: Regarding your **edit**, location queries will have an overhead as you don't have direct-access (unless you build a secondary index to get to say every 3x3 or 5x5 section).  However, surroundings checking is trivial as each node has pointers to all of its surrounding squares.